# Change status to APPROVED when multiple approvers approved the form

Tags: mysql

How to update a status column in a table named `applicationform`, when 6 users need to update the same form using PHP? If all of the 4 approvers approve the application then the application status turn to APPROVED. If only 1,2 or 3 approvers approve the application, it turn to DISAPPROVED.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or mysqli. You are asking a design question related to your schema

Comment: Please share more details. Why not run an `UPDATE` query to update the table?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a status column.

Have an approvals table which is a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) between applicationform and your users table.

Every time a user approves an application, add an entry to the approvals table (with whatever logic you need to ensure that they are authorised to make the approval and they haven't done so already).

Determine the status on demand by counting the number of entries in the approvals table which have the ID of the application form you are interested in.